# how to add tool tip to multiselect list box in .net html view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, listbox, tooltip, multi-select

This is the list box, I am trying to add a tooltip for each item in the list box.

Tool tip for each list item in the list box.

```html
@Html.ListBox("SelectedFunctions", new MultiSelectList(Model.AssignedFunctions,
"Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @style =
"height: 200px", @id = "listAssigned" })
```